# a data set of .... are or a data set of ... is

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

I always confused about using the word **data**. Sometimes, writers use it as a single word, while others use it as plural.

I really would like to understand the correct way to use word **data** in my sentence.

> A data of 300 observations are generated from a normal distribution.

or

> A data of 300 observations is generated from a normal distribution.

I think if we assumed that the word **data** is plural, then, I should not use the determiner **a** with it.

Which sentence is correct and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking (or at least traditionally), the singular of *data* is [*datum*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/datum). However, it's increasingly frequent that people simply use *data* in both singular and plural forms.

This is a strange word. When used in the singular, using the indefinite article is fine and the verb should be *is*. When used in the plural, there is no article and the verb is *are*. However, you also have the option of using *data* as an uncountable mass noun, with *is* and an optional definite article.

I would also say data *from* (or data *collected from*) rather than data *of*. And because of that, I would probably not use *from* a second time in the sentence.

So:

> 1. **A** datum / data from 300 observations **is** generated by using a normal distribution.
>   2. a) Data from 300 observations **are** generated by using a normal distribution.
>   2. b) (**The**) Data from 300 observations **is** generated by using a normal distribution.

This is one of those rare situations where either *is* or *are* can be used (in the last two versions) and both are actually correct.

It seems to me that unless you're talking about *Xs of* data or data *Xs* (*points of* data or data *points*, for instance), it's simpler to use the mass noun form—and forget about it being singular or plural and which word to use. However, I know that many scientific texts still follow the singular and plural forms.

What makes this tricky is that different people use it differently, and it's easy to confuse the different uses.

---

Even odder is that, in referring to Merriam-Webster on this, I discovered that the plural of *datum* can also be *datums*. (Something I hadn't known.) This makes things even more confusing.

Here is what [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/data#usage-1) says about the the word:

> **Is** ***data*** **singular or plural?: Usage Guide**
>
> *Data* leads a life of its own quite independent of *datum*, of which it was originally the plural. It occurs in two constructions: as a plural noun (like *earnings*), taking a plural verb and plural modifiers (such as *these*, *many*, *a few*) but not cardinal numbers, and serving as a referent for plural pronouns (such as *they*, *them*); and as an abstract mass noun (like *information*), taking a singular verb and singular modifiers (such as *this*, *much*, *little*), and being referred to by a singular pronoun (*it*). Both constructions are standard. The plural construction is more common in print, evidently because the house style of several publishers mandates it.